# How to add files on application path while creating docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-functions, azure-aks

I have deployed a http trigger function in Azure Kubernetes Service. I need some files that has to be kept on application path. How to add those files while creating the docker image..

steps I have followed

1. created a http trigger function on local
2. created docker image of that function
3. pushed the docker image in azure portal
4. deploying it in AKS

here is my file structure:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkLLO.png
here is my docker file:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE4Ny.png

myfirstfunc folder contains the index.js and function.json files. I have to add the music.mp3 and thankyou.mp4 files in my docker container..

my docker file:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot 
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

Comment: [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)ing them in your Dockerfile should work file; is there a more specific problem you're having?  Can you edit your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I have updated my file structure and docker file. can u pls help me with some samples on how to add those files on application path in docker file. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You seem to have added two links to images to the question.  Can you replace those with the actual text of the Dockerfile -- not a link, not an image?  When you say "on the application path", where are the files ending up, and where do you want them; what's the actual problem you're encountering?

Comment: It is actually a video compilation function where I get an array of videos and images from cloud as input and merge them into one using ffmpeg. Also adding music to that merged video. For this, I need music.mp3 and few other video clips on app path. I will read those files on my function. Added the docker file.